# Get java script values in jsp

Tags: jsp

Hi i've the below jsp created.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function show(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='none';
    }
function hide(x)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById(y).style.display='block';
    }


function myKeyPress(e,x,y){
    var keynum;
    if(window.event){ // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }else
    if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    //alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    //alert(keynum);
    if (keynum == 13) {
        //document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
        var m=document.getElementById(x).value;
        alert(m);
        hide(x,y);
        //document.form1.action="abc.jsp?val="+x;
        //document.form1.submit();
    }
}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="abc.jsp">
      <table width="722">
        <tr>
          <td width="431" height="190">
          <table width="439" >
            <tr>
              <td width="129">PARTS Updated</td>
              <td width="108"><p>
                <select name="PARTS_Updated" id="PARTS_Updated" >
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </p></td>
              <td width="186"><label for="PARTS_Updated"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>TSI OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_N/A" value="TSI_N/A" onClick="hide('TSI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
              <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="TSI_Query" value="TSI_Query" onClick="show('TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')">              TSI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="TSI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="TSI_Query_Box" id="TSI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none"  onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event,'TSI_Query_Box','SI_Query_Box')"></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="65">Special Ins OK&#13;</td>
              <td><p>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_N/A" value="TSI_OK" onClick="hide('SI_Query_Box')">
                N/A
              </p>
                <p>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="SI_Query" value="SI_Query" onClick="show('SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')"> SI Query</p></td>
              <td><label for="SI_Query_Box"></label>
                  <textarea name="SI_Query_Box" id="SI_Query_Box" cols="15" rows="5" style="display:none" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event,'SI_Query_Box','TSI_Query_Box')""></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
          <td width="279">
              <table width="279" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="87"><p>Shipment ID&#13;</p></td>
              <td width="97"><label for="Ship_ID" id="Ship_IDl"></label>
              <input type="text" name="Ship_ID" id="Ship_ID"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="721" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="374" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" id="Send for CT Review (SCTR)" value="Send for CT Review (SCTR)"></td>
          <td width="331" align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="CT Review Complete (CTRC" id="CT Review Complete (CTRC)" value="CT Review Complete (CTRC)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup Queries" id="Cleanup Queries" value="Cleanup Queries"></td>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="Cleanup  Complete" id="Cleanup  Complete" value="Cleanup  Complete"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Go_To_Main_Page" id="Go_To_Main_Page" value="Go To Main Page"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and second jsp as below

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="<%request.getParameter("TSI_Query_Box");%>">
        <input type="text" value="<%request.getParameter("SI_Query_Box");%>">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here i want to know how to retrieve the textarea values into the second jsp. i heard that i can use hidden values but not sure of how to use them. actually i want this data for submition in my database. please let me know how do i do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all your function `hide(x)` must have two parameters as:

```
function hide(x,y)
{
    document.getElementById(x).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(y).style.display='block';
}
```

and when you assign the value in JSP, you must use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`

so you must change your HTML to:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=request.getParameter("TSI_Query_Box")%>">
```

and also Take a look at the answer, [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1551233)

Answer (score 0):

At first change

```
<input type="text" value="<%request.getParameter("TSI_Query_Box");%>">
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="<%= request.getParameter("TSI_Query_Box"); %>">
```